# Live local coding in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can I make IntelliJ re-compile and run when I change the code? All I could find was this [infinitest](https://www.mkyong.com/intellij/intellij-infinitest-continuous-testing/) plugin that specifically runs all tests.

Maybe something similar to http://www.romaniancoder.com/spring-boot-live-reload-with-intellij/

Comment: instead of saving `cmd+s`, you could run the selected configuration by `ctrl+r` :)

Comment: @AndrewTobilko :mind-blown:!

Comment: There is **toggle auto-test** option in JUnit Run/Debug Configuration. When it is enabled and you have **Build project automatically** option enabled in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler settings, the IDE will re-compile the code on it's change.